# Please check the server log for more details. Original error: Unable to parse remote response

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, grid, appium

I'm trying to run tests on GRID3 using appium, but every run i receive this error

```
public static AndroidDriver<WebElement> initAndroidDriver() throws Exception {
        try {
            String apkLink = SettingsProvider.getPropertyValue("front.android.apk.link") +
                    "/" + SettingsProvider.getPropertyValue("front.android.version");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.ANDROID);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, apkLink);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, true);
            capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, false);
            capabilities.setCapability("appium:androidInstallTimeout ", 100000);
            return new AppiumBuilder().createAndroidApkDriver(new URL(getSeleniumMobileGridHost()), capabilities);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new Exception("Creating ANDROID driver exception " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Initialization Android driver Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: Unable to parse remote response: <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Any ideas how ti fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody changed link to grid in property config, added /wd/hub to link and everything started to work